# ContextMenu Close events not firing when another ContextMenu is open

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I though I had faulty logic somewhere in my project so I made a new project with just the following:

```
<Window>
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Test1"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Test2"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Test3"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Test4"/>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="TreeViewContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Click Me!"/>
            </ContextMenu>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewContextMenu}"/>
                <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuOpening" Handler="TreeViewContextMenu_Opening"/>
                <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuClosing" Handler="TreeViewContextMenu_Closing"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>   
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

When I right click (to open ContextMenu) while having ContextMenu open, the closing/closed event doesn't trigger, regardless if I have the event handler in ContextMenu, TreeViewItem or TreeView.

It doesn't happen when holding the right click or,of course, making a left click.

[Demonstration](https://streamable.com/u9glz4).

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you make multiple TreeViewItems share a ContextMenu? I don't see any good reason to do so. Your TreeView should be modified like the following.

```xml
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Test1"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Test2"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Test3"/>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Test4"/>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Click Me!"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuOpening" Handler="TreeViewContextMenu_Opening"/>
            <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuClosing" Handler="TreeViewContextMenu_Closing"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

**EDIT**

I checked the instance of ContextMenu of TreeViewItem at TreeViewContextMenu_Opening event handler.

```cs
private ContextMenu? _contextMenu;

private void TreeViewContextMenu_Opening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    var contextMenu = ((TreeViewItem)sender).ContextMenu;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Opening {contextMenu is not null}  {object.ReferenceEquals(contextMenu, _contextMenu)}");

    _contextMenu = contextMenu;
    _contextMenu.Closed += OnClosed;

    void OnClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ContextMenu)sender).Closed -= OnClosed;
        _contextMenu = null;
        Debug.WriteLine("Closed");
    }
}
```

I found that when a ContextMenu is opened while a ContextMenu is alreadly opened, the instance of ContextMenu was identical and ContextMenu.Closed event did not fire. That means in such case, the same ContextMenu is reused.

Naturally, you will have no chance to catch TreeViewContextMenu_Closing event because the ContextMenu will not be closed.

Comment: Alright, identical issue with your code too though.

Comment: I found that the ContextMenu will not be closed in such case.